# Lists with "padding" are not rendered correctly

Tags: bug, markdown, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistent/incorrect breaks/newlines in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123903/inconsistent-incorrect-breaks-newlines-in-lists)

List formatting behaves weirdly when I want to control padding between list levels. Intuitively, I'd write

```
- First level
  - Second level
  - Second level

- First level
  - Second level
  - Second level
```

And I'd expect the outcome to be similarly structured. Yet it turns out that the second level elements are "glued" to the subsequent first level elements:

- First level

  - Second level
  - Second level
- First level

  - Second level
  - Second level

A workaround is to put a comment in between:

```
- First level
  - Second level
  - Second level

<!-- abc -->

- First level
  - Second level
  - Second level
```

- First level

  - Second level
  - Second level

- First level

  - Second level
  - Second level

To me, that doesn't appear very reasonable.