# Show link to revision history when there are revisions but no edits

Tags: feature-request, questions, revisions-list

In the latest [Recent Changes FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/161595#161595) I saw this:

> 2013-02-18: The revision history of a question that was closed as a duplicate is now showing the chosen originals as part of the "Closed as duplicate" notice.

That sounds cool, so I went to go see what it looks like and realized that **questions with [revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/168761/revisions), but no edits, don't have an `"edited <date>"` link to click**.

This applies to questions which had a bounty posted, or have been closed, reopened, locked, deleted, etc.

Examples:

- [More activity to get Beta badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168761/more-activity-to-get-beta-badge), see [revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/168761/revisions).
- [Determine if a String is a number and convert in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5888987), see [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5888987/revisions).

> [image: no link]

I realize I can manually type the URL:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/168761/revisions
```

But it would be nice to simply click. It could say "revised" instead of "edited" if there were no edits:

> [image]

Comment: This really annoys me. You missed deleted off your list as well... There's a brilliant Shog9 rant somewhere where he says something about this as well... but I can't find it.

Comment: Manually constructing the URL and using "source" or "link" works great.

Comment: I agree with your idea. Maybe even make this a feature for users with over 101 rep, so that is isn't noise for casual readers.

Comment: @Frank Maybe even only to those with close privileges, since the information is irrelevant otherwise.

Comment: Also if the software is updated and [it changes the rendering of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2627/282094), making the bug reported seem invalid, there's nothing recorded. The post is simply altered without any record and no way to see what it looked like before the update, making another edit to restore the original appearance a challenge.

Answer (score 16):

Not only what Shog9 says. We have now had a case where a question was closed as dupe, then reopened, and then a discussion about the reopening started. And I didn't manage to see what the dupe question was until manually changing the address from `http:/....com/question/12345/i-have-a-question` to `http:/....com/post/12345/revisions`, in order to get the desired link (note how this is considered hacking in some countries? */sarcasm*).

Please, implement this! The correct information to show is probably either "*post modified 1 hour ago by Community*" or "*post reopened 1 hour ago by Community*".

Answer (score 10):

Normally, the revision history link only shows up when there've been *edits* to the post - there are a bunch of other things that can show up there that won't trigger the creation of the link (closing/reopening, deletion/undeletion, migration, locking, bounties, annotations, *tweeting*...)

For most casual *readers*, that's all just noise - they're interested in the current state of the question, *maybe* how the text has evolved over time, but not all the administrative minutia.

The close-as-duplicate record's kinda special though, since that *used to be* an edit - it *did* trigger the revision history link, and there was potentially some useful information there even if the post was later re-opened. Realistically, those links should probably show up somewhere else as well - comments, or the "linked" sidebar - but since those are deleted (either when the post is closed, or when it's re-opened), that's not working either.

For now, you can do what the rest of us process wonks do: install the [SE Modifications userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) and get a link to the revision history on *every* post (and occasionally some minor layout weirdness thrown in free of charge).

Comment: `For most casual readers, that's all just noise` They are already seeing all that "noise" if they click the `"edited <date>"` link (and a large percentage of questions have that link). Putting `"revised <date>"` where they are used to seeing `"edited <date>"` is hardly distracting. But those SE scripts sound interesting. I'll check them out.

Comment: No, I mean if there aren't any *edits* the information behind "revised" is just noise - the post itself hasn't changed, just its status (with, again, dup-links being the exception here since that history entry actually lists stuff that showed up on the question). Granted, it's noise that a lot of us are *very interested in*, but that doesn't matter to most of the folks visiting the site.

Comment: Do you think there are a large number of users that both don't care about that data *and* would be distracted/confused by that link being there (a link that is on many other questions already)? I can't speak for the all new users, but I clicked on everything when I was new to try to learn about SO.

Comment: The vast, *vast* majority of people visiting SO care not a whit about learning about SO. For the ones that do, it's still important to give them stuff that they can *use* first and foremost - if you log in as a new user, you'll quickly notice that there are a lot fewer links hanging around each post.

Comment: To your point: I've been on over a year and just now noticed this.

Comment: It's like boiling a frog... You increase the number of links slowly, so the frog barely notices that his comfortable home has suddenly become TVTropes.

Comment: How about making "marked as duplicate" a link to the revision history? Or even the date, like the "edited" one.

Comment: Except that info is most needed when the close notice *isn't* being displayed, @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ

Comment: Any chance for a re-evaluation, maybe only triggered by rep (1K, like the vote-counts)?

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to see "asked ..." linked to revs if there were no edits.

Answer (score 7):

While I still support this request, since January 2020, we have a [link to improved timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/152859) available always:

[image: link to timeline]

The timeline view is different from revisions, but still contains most, if not all, of the details.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Jan 2021), the link trick doesn't seem to work for me. It simply returns to the post.

Test: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168765/revisions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168765/revisions)

Comment: This never worked. You need to change "questions" to be "posts" in the link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/168765/revisions