# Can we have either "show revision history" or "redact" in the post mod actions menu?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, revisions-list, revision-redaction

The link for redacting PII (or whatever) from a post is available on the revision history page of a post. That's a sensible spot to put it, but it's a bit out of reach if the post does not yet have any edits made.

We can of course force the URL (i.e. visit `/posts/####/revisions`), but that can be cumbersome. You could also create an edit *then* make the redaction, but that just adds unnecessary noise.

There are [userscripts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) that add the link to revision history and I understand [why it's not available by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168766/216955), but could we have a link inserted into the post mod actions menu? Or as [Robert suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283527/can-we-have-a-show-revision-history-in-the-post-mod-actions-menu#comment918971_283530), a redact option in the menu?

> If an edit is needed to implement a redaction, then it should be a simple matter for the system create that edit when it knows what the moderator wants to remove. Add a 'redact' function to the 'mod' menu and make it a **ONE edit-and-redact** operation.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bad idea, although I should note that you *have* to have an edit on the post for redaction to work properly anyway, since otherwise the rendered HTML containing the sensitive information is cached...

So while you *can* redact the displayed revision and then make some trivial edit to trigger the re-render, you might as well just edit out the sensitive info normally and then redact the previous revision(s).

Comment: If that's the SE sanctioned workflow then I can work with that, but I'm not 100% clear on your explanation. The rendered HTML is cached where/by who? I removed a signature on [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/73912/revisions) just to do some redaction testing, but from what I can see it was a successful redaction. What's the harm in doing it that way?

Comment: We may have fixed that bug then :)

Comment: If an edit is needed to implement a redaction, then it should be a simple matter for the system create that edit when it knows what the moderator wants to remove. Add a 'redact' function to the 'mod' menu and make it a **ONE edit-and-redact** operation.

Comment: That would be a good feature-request, @RobertCartaino...

Comment: If caching is no longer an issue then I agree with @Robert, there's no point in having us edit the post twice. Either adding a revision history link to the menu or an option to redact would both be an improvement to the current workflow. I've added Robert's suggestion to the original post.