# What did Yaakov do to this post?

Tags: support, bump, timeline, homepage

Looking at the frontpage I saw this: ([direct link to question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post))

[image: question in front page]

I remembered seeing this as a really old question, so I decided to look what was changed in this question. First of all I though perhaps an answer was edited, but none of that took place. The most recent edit to the question however was by Yaakov, but not 8 mins ago, more like 4 months ago:
[image]
Looking at the timeline there was something that occurred roughly 8 mins ago (now 13 mins ago):
[image]
But this was not done by Yaakov, but by Sonic. So did I miss something, perhaps a deleted answer? Or is there a bug going on?

Comment: It says right there in your screenshot: Sonic protected the question. Now it can’t receive new answers from users with less than 10 rep earned on MSE.

Comment: @DanBron Yes it says that, but the frontpage says that Yaakov modified the post, not Sonic.

Comment: @DanBron Protecting [doesn't bump posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/377214). The post had actually been bumped as a result of an edit to a deleted answer by Yaakov, and edits on deleted answers do bump posts.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Protecting [does *not* bump posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/377214), so my protection of the question is *not* what caused it to be bumped.

What actually happened here is that there was a spam answer that contained an NSFW image. Some time after it was deleted, Yaakov redacted that image from the post. Redaction does have a flaw, in that it only modifies the Markdown of a given post's revision, while its prior rendered HTML remains unmodified, so [it's necessary to edit posts after redacting their most recent revision to remove all traces of what was redacted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283530/377214).

The bump here resulted from Yaakov's edit to do the above, to rebake the post so that the redacted image was no longer present in the cached HTML of the post. Editing deleted answers [still bumps the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/stop-an-edited-deleted-answer-from-bumping-the-question), so that's why you saw it bumped without any apparent (visible) recent activity.

Comment: Well that makes sense, although it sounds like there should be better ways for staff to get rid of unsavoury content then this cumbersome process.

Comment: Well in some situations - things are messy enough that these cumbersome processes are needed. While NSFW images are "hidden" for 10K users - Mods can see them. I'd be rather grateful not to be browsing MSE and coming across something like that, since mods can see it. Sometimes we do actually have to set things on fire. Then burn the ashes.

Answer (score 24):

> Redacted some porn
>
> Creates a small kerfuffle
>
> Answer [too complex](https://xkcd.com/1425/)

Comment: Thanks for protecting our innocent souls! ;-)